# Postgres JSON field update with ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql, activerecord

What's the best way to use `update` with a json field. I'd like my JSON field to accept new keys or update existing keys, but not overwrite the entire field. ActiveRecord does a nice job of just updating fields that changed, but I don't understand how to apply that to the sub-fields in the json record...

```
it 'can update settings with a plain object' do
  integration = Integration.create(
    name: 'Name',
    json_settings: {
      key1: 1,
      key2: 2
    }
  )
  integration.update(
    settings: { key2: 2 }
  )
  // json_settings is now { "key2": 3 } but I want
  // { "key1": 1, "key2": 3 } 
  expect(integration.json_settings['key1']).to eq('1') // fails
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code should look like:

```
it 'can update settings with a plain object' do
  integration = Integration.create(
    name: 'Name',
    json_settings: {
      key1: 1,
      key2: 2
    }
  )
  integration.json_settings = integration.json_settings.merge { key2: 3 }
  integration.save
  expect(integration.json_settings['key1']).to eq(1)
end
```

Comment: ok, that was what I was going to do, but wasn't sure if there was any rails way of updating that field with a merge by default.

Comment: yes, I'm curious if there is a way to get AR to do an atomic update too.  If not when this was asked, now in AR 5.2.  This answer doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: @jrochkind The question was not related to any atomic update either.

Comment: "accept new keys or update existing keys, but not overwrite the entire field"  -- "atomic update" may not be the right word for this, but that's one thing I've seen it called. This answer leads to AR code that updates the entire hash with AR's in-memory version.

Comment: Yeah the answer did it correct way. I think  you are thinking too deep on this which is not needed. There is nothing about *atomicity* at least in this question. What OP asked, not to remove old keys/values, rather do a **merge** operation.

Comment: I suspect if you want a 'merge update' you mean "merge into _what's in the db_ in a concurrency safe way", not just "merge into what's already in memory in this process/thread".  But if you want the latter, you are good, cause it's easy! if you want the former, this answer doesn't provide it, which is fine if you don't want it. The questioner says "but not overwrite the entire field", so I think they want the former. The answer here WILL overwrite the entire field. I don't believe there is anything in Rails to do otherwise at present, however.